# Why are the definitions of subtangent and subnormal different in Cartesian and polar systems?

Tags: calculus, geometry

As shown in the figure below, in a cartesian system, a curve, e.g. $f(x,y)=0$, if the tangent drawn at a point **P** on the curve be **PT**, the normal at that point be **PN** and **PA** is perpendicular to the X axis, then,

the subtangent is **TA** with the length $= y\frac{dx}{dy}$
and

the subnormal is **AN** with the length $= y\frac{dy}{dx}$

[image]

As shown in the figure below, in a polar system, a curve, e.g. $r=f(\theta)$, if the tangent drawn at a point **P** on the curve be **PT**, the normal at that point be **PN** and **PO** is perpendicular to the initial line **OX**, then,

the subtangent is **OT** with the length $= r^2\frac{d\theta}{dr}$
and

the subnormal is **ON** with the length $=\frac{dr}{d\theta}$
[image]

It is obvious that in both the systems the subtangent and the subnormal are respectively defined differently. By applying coordinate transformation to one system in order to get the other, the respective lengths of the subtangent and the subnormal will not remain the same as obtained directly using the definition in the respective system.

Is it just pure convention or is there some mathematics that I don't see?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like this is taken from wiki. On the wiki page they call the former sub-tan/norm as a projection onto the x-axis and call it ***POLAR*** sub-tan/norm when the coordinate system is polar and not cartesian coordinates.